# Errors: "Unable to find UnityARCore" and "DllNotFoundException"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, aar, arcore

I've built an ARCore app in Unity using the ARFoundation Package. Then I embedded Unity app inside a native Android app by following the instructions in this link: [Embedded Unity within Android App](https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a).

The AR app works fine as a Stand Alone app. But I'm getting the error while embedding it inside a native Android app:

```
E/Unity: Unable to find UnityARCore
E/Unity: DllNotFoundException: UnityARCore
at (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.XR.ARCore.Api:UnityARCore_setCameraPermissionProvider (UnityEngine.XR.ARCore.Api/CameraPermissionRequestProvider)
at UnityEngine.XR.ARCore.ARCoreCameraExtension.Register () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: maybe something useful [here](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/219)

Comment: @Vishnu were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @Vishnu, This question is now almost three years old! If you have found a solution to this issue please let the community know.

Answer (score 0):

When .aar file of library is generated, It does not include dependent jars/aars somehow.
Instead of including .aar we should add unity gradle library as module in our app. This solved issue for me.

[Here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uaal-example/blob/master/docs/android.md) is more details of how to include unity as a module in your app.